# SharedPreference doesn't save on Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am working with `SharedPreference` but I cannot save info.

These is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SharedPrefApp extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button buton1 , buton2 ;
    EditText etv1 , etv2 ;
    TextView tv1;
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bambam){
        super.onCreate(bambam);
        setContentView(R.layout.sharedpref_xml);
        buton1 = ( Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
        buton2 = ( Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
        etv1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        etv2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        buton1.setOnClickListener(this);
        buton2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button12:
                sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("namapassword" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putString("isim" , etv1.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("sifre" , etv2.getText().toString());
                editor.apply();
                Toast.makeText(this , "Kaydedildi" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button13:
                sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("namepassword" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String a = sharedPref.getString("isim", "olmadı");
                String b = sharedPref.getString("sifre" , "olmadı");
                tv1.setText(a + " " + b);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Gosterildi" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

It returns `olmadı olmadı` in application. Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Last sentence, made my day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. You spelled `name` as `nama`, resulting in that you are trying to store and fetch values from two different preferences.

Your first button (`R.id.button12`) call to get shared preferences is:

```
sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("namapassword" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
```

change it to:

```
sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("namepassword" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
```

Comment: Thanks so much Marcus

Comment: Anytime. Happy coding! @Bad0

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using  editor.apply() method
try to using commit() method

For example

```
editor.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
   sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("namapassword" , Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
   sharedprefs.edit.putString("isim" , etv1.getText().toString()).commit();
```

Oh Boy... Your getString shouldb like the follows..

```
String a = sharedPref.getString("isim", null);
String b = sharedPref.getString("sifre" , null);
```

Comment: there is no error in logcat , but it returns "olmadı" which second parameter of getString method